# Swiping to delete a cardview causes flickering for a brief second before animating

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-cardview, android-cursorloader

I have implemented cardview in my application with the feature swipe right to delete. The moment I swipe right the card view goes and comes back for one tenth of a second and then gain goes off causing flickering.

My code goes like this for the swipe touch listener.I am updating the Content resolver as well notifying the adapter.

```
SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
            new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(recyclerView,
                    new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                Post post = posts.get(position);
                                post.setIsDeleted(true);
                                getActivity().getContentResolver().update(PostsContract.PostEntry.buildUriForPost(posts.get(position).get_ID()), Utility.changePostToContentValue(post), "_id=" + post.get_ID(),null);
                                posts.remove(position);
                                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

                            }

                        }
                    });
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);
```

My onLoadFinished Looks like this

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    if(data!=null && data.getCount() != posts.size()){
        posts.clear();
        while (data.moveToNext()){
            Post post = new Post(data);
            posts.add(post);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

When I put break points. It works fine in the handler onDismissedSwipeByRight where the deleted card isn't visible. But when it comes to OnLoadFinished break point I see the deleted card came back and then goes off automatically after the function executes even though the size of posts Arraylist is exactly same.

Since the deleted card comes back for one tenth of a second.This causes a flicker. Can anyone tell me where I a going wrong ?

Comment: Why do you have a `for loop` inside of `onDismissedBySwipeRight`?

Comment: reverseSortedPositions is an array . But it only runs once.

Comment: add some timing code to see just how long each line takes. My assumption is that you are doing way too much work in that method.

Comment: Are you talking about onDismissedBySwipeRight ?

Comment: yes, basically you are doing too much inside that method. I am pretty sure that is the issue. You should only have the last 2 statements in the for statement. All others I think don't belong there. Ummm are there other methods you can override? Maybe after the swipe is finished, you can do the other code???

Comment: Nope there no other methods to override.

Comment: Again, test how long each call is taking, I think you are using that method heavily, and it should only be light-weight calls.

Comment: try to remove canSwipe() method.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in the [docs](https://github.com/brnunes/SwipeableRecyclerView), I see that the example also calls `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` like so:

```
SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
            new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(recyclerView,
                    new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                Post post = posts.get(position);
                                post.setIsDeleted(true);
                                getActivity().getContentResolver().update(PostsContract.PostEntry.buildUriForPost(posts.get(position).get_ID()), Utility.changePostToContentValue(post), "_id=" + post.get_ID(),null);
                                posts.remove(position);
                                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    });
```

The reason for your problem might be that the listener takes care of making the view swipe to the right, but once the gesture is complete, it takes the view back to normal so it can be reused. You can try making the view GONE until it is reused by the recyclerview (make it visible in the adapter).